# PayPal Plus API and PHP: Payments not possible

Tags: php, paypal

I created a REST Api for PayPal Plus. Somehow payments are not being processed. After my order I successfully get directed to the paypal page where I can see an overview of my order. However, when I click "Paying" I DO NOT get forwarded to the paypal confirmation page, but get redirected to the return URL of my shop.

My PHP code:

```
$money = '0.01';
$mode = 'live';
$cientID = '123456';
$clientSecret = '123456';

$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        $cientID,     
        $clientSecret      
    )
);
$apiContext->setConfig(
    array(
        'mode' => $mode
    )
);

$item1 = new \PayPal\Api\Item();
$item1->setName('My order')
    ->setCurrency('EUR')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setPrice($money);

$itemList = new \PayPal\Api\ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item1));

$payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('EUR');
$amount->setTotal($money);

$transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount);
$transaction->setItemList($itemList);
$transaction->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());
$transaction->setDescription('My order');

    $host = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$redirectUrl = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrl->setReturnUrl($host . '/page.php');
$redirectUrl->setCancelUrl($host . '/page.php');

$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale');
$payment->setPayer($payer);
$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrl);
$payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

$payment = $payment->create($apiContext);

$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
```

My JS:

```
var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
   "approvalUrl": "<?=$approvalUrl?>",
   "placeholder": "ppplus",
   "mode": "live",
   "country": "DE"
});
```

Can anyone see a problem?

Comment: It’s very hard to work out what’s doing what. From what you’ve written it looks like you’re trying to print the approvalUrl before you’ve had the transaction approved? How do these files work together? How does the JS get printed to the page – and when?

Comment: Where are you setting `$apiContext` in `$payment = $payment->create($apiContext);`  ?  See **Execute payment** at bottom of [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/payments/#execute-payment)